# What happens if a Python thread dies after acquiring a lock?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

In my program I have a thread that just sends and gets updates from a server. I try to handle exceptions gracefully, but just in case the thread dies I'd simply like to restart it. The problem is the thread acquires locks (Threading.RLock objects) before using certain resources, and I don't know what happens if the thread were to die after acquiring a lock but before releasing it. How could I deal with such a situation?

Comment: What constitutes dying? How are you acquiring the locks? Exceptions will auto-release any lock acquired as a `with` statement context manager as they propagate up the stack, but if dying means deadlock or you're acquiring locks unsafely, you might not get such nice guarantees.

Comment: @user2357112 dying as in an exception gets thrown that I don't handle, and the thread exits, and calls to mythread.is_alive() return false. Could you explain more about threading and the with statement?

Comment: The documentation shows how to use a lock as a context manager and explains `with` statements: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#predefined-clean-up-actions http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/ https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with

Comment: @user2357112 Very good points. You should probably rewrite your two comments as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [acquire your locks using `with` statements](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement):

```
with whatever_lock:
    do_stuff()
```

or in properly constructed try-finally statements (less recommended, but sometimes necessary):

```
whatever_lock.acquire()
try:
    do_stuff()
finally:
    whatever_lock.release()
```

then if an exception occurs, the locks will be released as the exception propagates out of the control flow constructs in which the locks are acquired.

That means if you're doing things right, dying threads will generally release all their locks as they die. On the other hand, if you don't acquire your locks safely, or if thread death can mean deadlock instead of unhandled exceptions, then locks may stay acquired when a thread dies.

Comment: This is just what I needed! I had sort of been cowboy coding and this is the first time I've ever used threads and didn't really read up on how to safely acquire locks. I took care to prevent any deadlocks or race conditions, but was vulnerable to unhanded exceptions.

The try-finally statement seems the way to go if I need to try to acquire a lock but with a specified timeout. I don't really see how I would do that using with statements.